# How do I write this equation in c++

Tags: c++, equation

what I've come up with is:
Payment = (rate * (1.0 + rate) * pow(madepayments)) / ((1.0 + rate) * pow(madepayments) -1.0) * loan

It's telling me "no instance of overloaded function pow matches the argument list. Argument types:double

Code:

```
double rate, payment, loan, madepayments, name, paidback,interestpaid;    

cout << "Enter the loan amount: "; 
cin >> loan; 
cout << "Enter the annual interest rate: "; 
cin >> rate; 
cout << "Enter the number of payments made: "; 
cin >> madepayments; 
cout << "Enter the customer's name: "; 
cin >> name; 
payment = (rate * (1.0 + rate) * pow(madepayments)) / ((1.0 + rate) * pow(madepayments) - 1.0) * loan;
```

Comment: Did the picture get posted with it? I can't tell, this is my first time using the site.

Comment: show your code please.

Comment: {
 double rate, payment, loan, madepayments, name, paidback, interestpaid;
 
 cout << "Enter the loan amount: ";
 cin >> loan;
 
 cout << "Enter the annual interest rate: ";
 cin >> rate;
 
 cout << "Enter the number of payments made: ";
 cin >> madepayments;

 cout << "Enter the customer's name: ";
 cin >> name;

 payment = (rate * (1.0 + rate) * pow(madepayments)) / ((1.0 + rate) * pow(madepayments) - 1.0) * loan;

Comment: Edit your question and add the code.

Comment: done, I think. sorry I'm a total noob to this site.

Comment: What do you think the `pow` function does?

Comment: It's the power function, an exponent, instead of using an "^"

Comment: Do you think that calculates `e^x`?

Comment: I tried to post the picture of what the assignment was, but apparently I need a higher rep on the site to do so, it calls for certain portions of the equation to be raised to the power "n", which is number of payments.

Comment: I think you're trying to tell me it needs a value before it will work.

Comment: Place the link of the image by this means and I will add it

Comment: Place the link of the image of your equation by this means and I will add it

Comment: https://blackboard.ccri.edu/bbcswebdav/pid-1159973-dt-content-rid-7526417_1/courses/12318.201710/CPP2.pdf

Comment: let me know if that actually opens for you. I'm having trouble figuring out how to post images to this site, I don't have anywhere to upload and host the picture currently.

Comment: Can not access, requires authentication.

Comment: Upload to dropbox, drive, etc.

Comment: I'm in the process of setting up the dropbox, but I fleshed out the code a little more, and it seems to have fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: pow() takes two parameters, not one: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/. Redo your question, reformulate it, try to describe your problem in a human language first, shows the formula using simple mathematics syntax or Excel syntax, and after that, your tries coding.

Answer (score 2):

[Pow](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/) expects another argument describing the exponent.